# CakePHP controller name in behavior

Tags: cakephp, behavior

I created relation Post hasMany Photos, Photos actsAs ImageBehavior.

How put to `$data['Photo']['model'] = 'Post'`? Automated?

Comment: explain more what are you asking about...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking about but when you have a form, you can simply add to your `$this->data['Photo']['model']` any value you want with hidden fields.

> // photo/add.ctp:
>
> ```
> $this->Form->create('Photo');
> $this->Form->input('model', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' =>'yourvalue'));
> $this->Form->end('Submit');
> ```

### Update

You can set this value after the form was submitted, so even if someone will replace the hidden field value you can just check it.

```
function add(){
    if(!empty($this->data['Photo']['model']){
       $this->data['Photo']['model'] = "yourvalue";
       $this->Photo->save($this->data));
    }
    else
       rest of the code...
}
    rest of the code
```

Comment: This is no good solutions, because User can set replace value for hidden fields...

Comment: You can set the value in your controller after the form was submited.